# VNC/Screen Mirroring over raspberry pi 4 hotspot

Tags: raspbian, wifi, vnc, wifi-direct

So far found ways to set up a VNC server with the local network. However, I'm looking for a way to create a hotspot that bridges a wifi connection on the pi and host a VNC server (such as RealVNC) or some sort of screen sharing application over the hotspot.

Then, I could have virtually any mobile device or pc connect to the hotspot and view the contents of the screen through the localhost in a browser (while all other traffic would be passed through connected wifi).

In essence, my goal is to share the contents of the pi 4 screen over a direct connection with a client device. Would this be possible?
And if so, would I need some sort of wifi adapter/dongle to bridge wifi to a wifi connection, along with additional programs to handle internet traffic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In essence, my goal is to share the contents of the pi 4 screen over a
>   direct connection with a client device. Would this be possible?

Yes. You should make the `wlan0` act as a wifi hotspot simple by this link:
[Setting up a Raspberry Pi as a Wireless Access Point](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md)

Then, install your favorite VNC server on the raspberry pi. Take note that VNC Server is included with Raspbian but you have to enable it by `raspi-conf` or you can install other packages.

For `RealVNC` that you mentioned, follow procedure below:

Install indeed package by:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install realvnc-vnc-server
```

After all of this, add `wlan0`'s IP address to your VNC client/viewer to connect to the by form your phone, etc.

---

> And if so, would I need some sort of wifi adapter/dongle to bridge
>   wifi to a wifi connection, along with additional programs to handle
>   internet traffic?

If you want to connect to your router by this structure:

```
"Smartphones"_Wifi ––> <–– "wlan0_"RPi"_eth0" ––> <–– Ethernet_"Router"_Ethernet ––> <–– Internet
```

You don't need any more wifi adapter/dongle. But, if you mean this structure:

```
"Smartphones"_Wifi ––> <–– "wlan0_"RPi"_wlan1" ––> <–– Wifi_"Router"_Ethernet ––> <–– Internet
```

As you see, you need another wireless adaptor (`wlan1`) to connect to the wireless interface of the router.

Comment: Yeah I am going to need an adapter as I'll primarily be connecting this to a public network and not my home one, hence the need for the connection bridge. Once I do set up a wlan0 and wlan1 though, will the pi do the rest for me, in terms of differentiating between internet and localhost traffic?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean but you can configure it as a bridge. Look at the second example of this answer, the `wlan1` would be your WAN port which is in DHCP mode and `wlan0` is the Local port that you need to enable hotspot on it and set a static IP address then configure `dnsmasq` to act as a DHCP server for the clients that are going to be connected.